# puppeteer(chromium) cannot work on nodejs production server

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, backend, chromium

I have a backend api that receives the HTML string sent from frontend and use puppeteer to generate a pdf file then return the raw data to front end.

```
exports.createPdf = async (req, res) => {
    const { resumeContent, pageSize } = req.body;
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent(resumeContent);
    const resumePdf = await page.pdf(
        {
            margin: {
                top: '20px',
                bottom: '20px'
            },
            format: pageSize
        }
    );
    await browser.close();
    const base64ResumePdf = resumePdf.toString('base64');
    res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Length': base64ResumePdf.length
    });
    res.send(base64ResumePdf);
};
```

All work perfectly in local environment.

However, on production(and UAT) server, the request status is always pending for 30s and then becomes canceled. And if I double click the canceled request, it will get into 404 page on our offical website without any useful info.
[image]

[image]

I could only doubt that puppeteer cannot work properly on a real server.
Maybe there is some restriction or authentication on opening chromium?

Does anyone have suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-aws-lambda

Our production server is on AWS EC2, so it seems that I need to make some EC2 or lambda operations.